# Limiting readers on a pipe

Tags: scripting, security, pipe, lsof, checksum

I want to use a pipe to pass some security credential information from "process1" to another script. I only want authorized reader processes to be permitted to read the pipe. I am thinking I will create a temp pipe with process1, and only write to the pipe if the reader is a process is digitally signed or has a chksum that has been registered prior to the run.  Has anyone done something similar and have any suggestions?

Comment: A named pipe? Just restrict the permissions. `(umask 77 && mkfifo pipe) || exit`

Answer (score 2):

You can try to exchange some credentials before sending the secret, but I think this will make your communication more difficult then necessary.

When I had to do a similar setup, I just encrypted the information with a symmetric-key algorithm and sent it out to whoever asked for it. Since only the intended recipient had the key to decrypt the information, any other listeners would be kept in the dark. If you go that route, make sure there is not enough information to do some statistical analysis of the encrypted data.

This would limit **what** information the readers can get from the pipe, it does not limit **the number** of readers, but the latter is not what I think you asked for.